# Craft Commerce: Creating Customer Accounts?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

**I just want to confirm how accounts are created for customers in Craft Commerce.**

Currently in the the Craft Commerce download the checkout processes provides the option to "login" or proceed with as a "guest" just providin the email. Is this the method of creating a customer account OR do we have to activate public registrations and point people to a registration page?

I'm a little unsure what needs putting into effect here. Any documentation people can point me to would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you want users to be able to register, you would need to allow public registrations and implement your own standard registration form:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form

When they enter their email as a guest (anonymous) user a 'guest' customer record is created and related to the current cart, but it is not associated with a craft user account. This customer record is not retrievable and is only created for the purpose of having a related customer to the current order. There is no way to see this customer record in the back-end.

If the user is logged in a related customer record is created that has a 1:1 relationship with the user. The same customer record is used every time the useris logged in. This customer is the central place that addresses and orders are related to. If you want to see the previous orders for a customer, add the "Customer Info" field to your user profile custom fields.

Comment: What would happen to an order if someone was using as a guest and then decided to register for an account? Would that order be then assigned to the customer's account?

Comment: @DanLee yes, past orders are assigned based on the email address.

Comment: This may be of some interest if you want a more integrated, during checkout, registration process - https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceRegisterOnCheckout

Comment: I am importing some users (using bob’s import plugin) who have a email address which they used in the past to place an order. Yet the Customer Info remains empty. 

Is there more to it?

Comment: Ok when I as an admin login as one of those newly imported users then later all their orders show up under _Customer Info_.